# Does Android Studio compress classes.dex file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, dex

It seems like the `classes.dex` of apk file in output folder is something different from the one of installed app.

I'm using classes.dex file for some security issues, so usually I unzipped the final apk file and got informations from `classes.dex` file. But when I read classes.dex file at runtime file size is so different. (8MB vs 46KB)

App itself is working great. Someone said that Proguard makes classes.dex file lighter but I turned off Proguard. (useProguard false, minifyEnabled false in build.gradle)

Is there anything I can try? Thank you in advance.

One sentence summary :
`classes.dex` of the `app/build/outputs/apk/app.apk` file built by Android Studio differs from the `classes.dex` that I could find from actual app installed location of Android device.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Abhi I added summary :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, android studio does the **conversion** and the term you used 'compress' happens by default while building.

The compilation process for Android apps is very different from other Java applications. But it begins in the same way: your Java source code files are compiled into `.class` files using the `javac` command:[image: conversion_to_class_file]

The .class files contain standard Oracle JVM Java byte-codes. But Android devices don’t use this byte-code format. Instead, Android has its own distinct byte-code format called Dalvik. Dalvik byte-codes, like Oracle JVM byte-codes, are machine-code instructions for a theoretical processor.

The compilation process needs to convert the `.class` files, and any `.jar` libraries into a single classes.dex file containing Dalvik byte-codes. This is done with the `dx` command:
This is how your `classes.dex` file is generated.

[image: conversion_to_dex_file]

The `classes.dex` file and the resources from your application, such as images and layouts, are then compressed into a zip-like file called an Android Package or `.apk` file. This is done with the Android Asset Packaging Tool or `aapt`:

[image: conversion_to_apk_file]

Your proguard rules, during the build process, help to

- Shrink – detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes.
- Optimize – analyzes and optimizes the bytecode of the methods.
- Obfuscate – renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names.

Hope it helps you to some extent.
If you want to know more about on how android apps are built and run,
[Read this.](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run)
**Source:** 
https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run

.